# change(rewrite) json object's property value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I've got stringify JSON object in which I try to change value of it's property `"quantity"`

```
"[{"name":"Butter","image":"/static/images/items/dairy/butter.jpg",
"price":" 30 uah","quantity":"1","alias":"butter"},   
{"name":"Chesse","image":"/static/images/items/dairy/cheese.jpg",
"price":" 60 uah","quantity":"1","alias":"chesse"}]"
```

So I get property value `json[0].quantity` and try to rewrite it like 
that

`var quantity = parseInt(json[0].quantity); 
 json[0].quantity = String(quantity + 1);`

But it's doesn't work. `"quantity"` property stays constant. Please help

Comment: It should work http://jsbin.com/tinusa/edit?js,console,output

Comment: @Shyju it's work for [{"prop": ''value"}] but not for "[{"prop": "value"}]"

Comment: that is a string which you need to convert to a js object using `JSON.parse`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you have json string you first need to parse it in to json and to increment quantity property you first need it to parseInt:

```js
var jsonString = '[{"name ":"Butter","image":"/ static / images / items / dairy / butter.jpg ","price":"30 uah","quantity":"1","alias":"butter"},{"name":"Chesse","image":"/static/images/items/dairy/cheese.jpg","price":" 60 uah","quantity":"1","alias":"chesse"}]';
console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonString))
var product = JSON.parse(jsonString);
product[0].quantity = parseInt(product[0].quantity)+1;

alert(product[0].quantity);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try to parse this json into a javscript object, using

```
json = JSON.parse(json)
```

Then you can try your old code and it should work out.  Also, to turn it back into json just use

```
JSON.stringify(json)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure my the example code in the question doesn't work.

Try this and you'll see that it works:

```
var json = [{
    "name": "Butter",
    "image": "/static/images/items/dairy/butter.jpg",
    "price": " 30 uah",
    "quantity": "1",
    "alias": "butter"
}];
var quantity = parseInt(json[0].quantity);
json[0].quantity = String(quantity + 1);
console.log(json[0]);
```

Output:

```
Object {name: "Butter", image: "/static/images/items/dairy/butter.jpg", price: " 30 uah", quantity: "2", alias: "butter"}
```

As you can see, quantity shows 2 now.

I'm not sure why you would want to keep numeric values as string, but that's a different subject.