# Access Javascript Object with changing values

Tags: javascript, json

If I have a JSON, for example:

```
   {
   "test1":{
      "test11":"someting",
      "test12":"something else"
   },
   "test2":{
      "test21":"asdasd",
      "test22":"qwasd"
   }
}
```

I want to access and modify some data but i don't know which one. 
I'll have an array of keys like this:

`["test2","test22"]` and a value: `"change to this"`.

I want to change the `myjson.test2.test22` data to `"change to this"`.

Is there some simple and elegant way to do this?

Note that I don't know what the array's content will be, so I cant use the `myjson.test2.test22` access method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [change(rewrite) json object's property value in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34426614/changerewrite-json-objects-property-value-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and walk the path. Then assign the value to the object with the last key.

```js
var object = { "test1": { "test11": "someting", "test12": "something else" }, "test2": { "test21": "asdasd", "test22": "qwasd" } },
    path = ["test2", "test22"],
    lastKey = path.pop();

path.reduce(function (o, k) {
    return o[k];
}, object)[lastKey] = 'change to this';

console.log(object);
```

For unknow properties, i suggets to make a check befor and use a default object then.

```js
var object = { "test1": { "test11": "someting", "test12": "something else" }, "test2": { "test21": "asdasd", "test22": "qwasd" } },
    path = ["test2", "test22", "42"],
    lastKey = path.pop();

path.reduce(function (o, k) {
    (o[k] !== null && typeof o[k] === 'object') || (o[k] = {});
    return o[k];
}, object)[lastKey] = 'change to this';

console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```js
    function setDeep(obj, props, value) {
      var cur = obj,
        prop;

      while ((prop = props.shift()) && props.length) {
        cur = cur[prop]
      }

      cur[prop] = value
      return obj;
    }

    var obj = {
      "test1": {
        "test11": "someting",
        "test12": "something else"
      },
      "test2": {
        "test21": "asdasd",
        "test22": "qwasd"
      }
    }

    setDeep(obj, ['test1', 'test12'], 'new value');

    console.log(obj)
```

Comment: This is also a great answer. I accepted another because that was somewhat more "elegant" in my opinion. Thank you though.

Answer (score 1):

Following is a recursive function the traverses the keys of an object until the matching key (last one in the array) is found then it's value is changed and the changed object is returned. base case is when the array of keys is empty. Returns false if the key is not found

given an object named obj

```
var obj =    {
   "test1":{
      "test11":"someting",
      "test12":"something else"
       },
       "test2":{
          "test21":"asdasd",
          "test22":"qwasd"
       }



 function changeAkey(object, arrayOfKeys, value){
   if(arrayOfKeys.length == 0)
      return value;
   else{
      if(!object[arrayOfKeys[0]])
         return false;
      else
         object[arrayOfKeys[0]] = changeAkey(object[arrayOfKeys[0]], arrayOfKeys.slice(1), value);
         return object;
   }
}
```

so `changeAkey(obj, ["test2", "test22"], value)` would do the job

Comment: The problem is, that this array is from user input. So i cant hardcode an "if" statement. I have to iterate through the array and access the obj by the elements.

Comment: I already did it. The Array:['test1', 'test12'] and the value: 'new value' is from user

Answer (score 0):

I would start by checking if the property exists and if it does change the data. This way it won't throw an unspecific error.

```
var keys = ["key1", "key2"];
var myObj = {
  "random1": {
    "random2": "someting",
    "random3": "something else"
  },
  "key1": {
    "random4": "asdasd",
    "key2": "qwasd"
  };
}

var hasKeys = myObj[keys[0]][keys[1]] || null;
if(hasKeys) {
  myObj[keys[0]][keys[1]] = "some data";
} else {
  console.log('property not found');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would propose to serialize your object and use String `replace()`. It works for any depth and simple code.

```
var objStr = JSON.stringify(obj);

changes.forEach(function(item){
   objStr = objStr.replace(item, to);   
})

obj = JSON.parse(objStr);
```

```js
var obj = {
   "test1":{
      "test11":"someting",
      "test12":"something else"
   },
   "test2":{
      "test21":"asdasd",
      "test22":"qwasd"
   }
}


var changes = ["test11", "test21"];
var to = 'change to this';

var objStr = JSON.stringify(obj);

changes.forEach(function(item){
   objStr = objStr.replace(item, to);   
})

obj = JSON.parse(objStr);
console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var obj =  {
 "test1":{
  "test11":"someting",
  "test12":"something else"
 },
 "test2":{
  "test21":"asdasd",
  "test22":"qwasd"
 }
};

var keys = ["test2","test22"];

function update_obj(obj, keys, value) {

 for (var i = 0; i < keys.length - 1; i++) {
  obj = obj[keys[i]];
 }
 obj[keys[keys.length - 1]] = value;
}
update_obj(obj, keys, "hi");

console.log(obj);
```